# c++ how to detect main window has just appeared after splash screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to build app which detects once main window appears after splash screen.
Now, I can execute application via ShellExecute() and fetch process id from SHELLEXECUTEINFO.
Here's my code for ShellExecute().

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
    {
        sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
        sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
        sei.hwnd = NULL;
        sei.lpVerb = NULL;
        sei.lpFile = binaryPath;
        sei.lpParameters = NULL;
        sei.lpDirectory = NULL;
        sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
        sei.hInstApp = NULL;
    }

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    return ShellExecuteEx(&sei)
```

So for now, I want to detect main window of application has just appeared after splash screen by its process id.
I've been searching the solution for this issue, but I have never found it because maybe my googling skill is very terrible.
Is there anyway to solve this issue?
Maybe example code is much better.

Comment: _"...I've found solution for this issue, ..."_: If you have found a solution, what are you asking?

Comment: sorry for wrong typos

Comment: unclear what you asking. *after splash screen* ? this is what ? *main window* ? which window ?

Comment: when you execute Adobe photoshop, you can see splash screen including "Adobe Photoshop cs..." sth like this. When splash screen disappears, you can use photoshop.

Comment: I mean that like in photoshop, main window is place where we can use main functionality of application.

Comment: Is my description clear?

Comment: how `ShellExecuteEx` related to all this ? for which app you asking ? and anyway - about what you asking ? how detect some window (name,class) or what ?

Comment: I want to fetch window handle(HWND) once main window appears.
In terms of apps, I want every apps.

Comment: what is *main* window ?

Comment: For example, if you use visual studio IDE, the main window is place where we can edit our code and configure solution settings even create solutions and etc.

Comment: maybe there's right words for main window, but I can't mention about it. sorry

Comment: for windows not exist property "main" window. window can visible or invisible, message only, layered, have different styles. etc.. but not exist "main". this is only you decide what is "main" window. in general (for unknown application) no solution

Comment: as you can know, ms windows is event-driven.

Comment: so I decided to try with setwineventhooks(). what do you think about this?

Comment: Use Spy++ to look at the "main window". You will see class name, window styles and so on, which make this window specific. Create winevent hook or windows hook to react when new window is created. Compare with the properties which you have determined using Spy++.

Comment: @zett42, I've already implemented via windows hook - cbthook, but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us this code what you have tried, else we can't help.

Comment: Sorry. I removed code about it. because we determined that we cannot solve this issue via setwindowshook - cbthook. so I can't show you my code now.

Comment: maybe there's other kind of hook but we don't know what hook is exactly fit for this issue.

Comment: Don't use a CBT hook. Use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) instead, and monitor window creation. You will have to know window class and/or title ahead of time, as there is no way to identify what you believe to be a *"main window"*.

Comment: @iInspectable, your idea is good. I thought like that.
But which event is so fit?
We cannot determine which thing is prefer to use for this

Comment: I'm sure the documentation I linked to is exhaustive. Don't expect use to read it for you.

Comment: ok, I see. I have to read and let you know what my idea is.